# Vite Library Mode Using Query Params inside React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget, vite

TL;DR:
When I get a build in my vite js project, there are multiple js files, one of them index.js, which imports my main react script. In my react script how do I get the queries that is entered from the `script`, tag? index.js can reach them via `import.meta.url` but how my react app will do it?.

I have created a widget with react, in my react app I get query params from `import.meta.url`

my script injected into HTML like this `<script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx?exampleQuery=123"></script>`

it works in dev mode.

but when I build my project,

an `index.js`created which all it's do is importing my react app like

`import "./main-SOMEHASH.js"`, which means that I'm no longer able to reach to `queries`inside my react app, it's defined in `index.js`

If I manually change the import statement in `index.js` to `import ./main-SOMEHASH.js?exampleQuery=123` it works.

but I need it to be dynamic.

If I change `index.js` 's content to:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(new URL(import.meta.url));
const modelHash = urlParams.get("exampleQuery");
import(`./main-y1A-E6X6.js?exampleQuery=${exampleQuery})`);
```

Again it'll work but in this case I'd need to change `index.js` each time I get a build.

Is there an easier way, or best practice for this?

finally my vite.config.js

```
  build: {
    minify: "terser",
    lib: {
      entry: "./src/main.jsx",
      name: "Widget",
      fileName: "index",
      formats: ["es"],
    },
  },
```